# Write file from bytearray in same format that was before conversion

Tags: android, byte, arrays, fileoutputstream

I have a file that was saved in database as a bytearray. I want to write the byte array to file at the same format that was before conversion into bytearray. For example if the file was docx i want to write as docx.

try 
         { 
                x = "/sdcard";
                x+= "/temp.pdf";

```
         FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(x); 
         try 
         {
            stream.write(array);
            stream.close();
         } 
         catch (IOException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
      { 
         e1.printStackTrace(); 
         x="";
      }
```

Comment: what conversion are you talking about?

Comment: are your files just documents or there are pictures,videos etc.?i am asking this because if we find extension of just images,or just documents it will be more available than this issue.for example getting extension of image you can use this:
imgReader.getFormatName();

Comment: the documents will be only pdf,doc,docx,txt